# Install SAS PCI adapter on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: pci-express, sas, broadcom

I have some difficulties to install a [LSI 3081e SAS adapter](https://www.ebay.fr/itm/Gigabyte-GC-RLE086-RH-LSI-1068E-HBA-card-8-port-SAS-SATA-PCI-E-array-card-3081E/192653365540?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649).

I am not even sure that it is possible on a Ubuntu server 20.04 as the card is quite old.

The card seems to be listed in `/sys/devices` (I have a pci0000:00 listed) but not with `lspci`.
I can not find drivers for ubuntu or windows 10.

If it is not possible, what card, at a reasonable price, could I get to use SAS hdds ?

`> dmesg` https://pastebin.com/zifzRrBc

`> sudo lspci -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0150] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0162] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:1e12] (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1e18] (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e44] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:1e02] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge [1b21:1080] (rev 03)
```

Comment: If the card is listed in `/sys`, but not with `lspci`, then something is really really wrong. Please re-check. Your hardware needs to be detected, and then a driver needs to be loaded for it. Check `dmesg` after boot to see if that happens, if there are any errors, or if the card is just ignored.

Comment: I don't see the device listed at all. `pci0000:00` should be the host bridge, not your card. Can you give some details about what you think you find in `/sys`? At the moment, I'd say the card is not detected at all, which points to a hardware problem. Possibly the card is defect (if you bought in on ebay).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The seller tells the card was tested but he still reimbursed me. But I was also thinking that there is compatibility issues.